# How can JNI async callback in C++?

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I am making a sample application in java and have defined some native methods.  Native method implementation is in C++.

Until this point everything is working fine. I am pursuing the following sample code:

http://codebazaar.blogspot.com/2010/08/package-codebazaar.html

The code is running fine. But now I want to design async call back mechanism.

*What I want:*

I want that C++ calls back to java after some certain period of time. In that period I will do some processing on the C++ side.  After processing completion I want to inform java that I have completed the process and return some values.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have seen it done in the OpenJDK, I don't remember the specifics, but I would down load its source and use it as an example.  The `File` class does this in a few places.

Comment: In this post, we talk [about the callback in jni][1]. I think it is useful for you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616362/interface-java-with-c-timer-library-using-jni/11624447#11624447

Comment: what did you find out?